# Php regex to match full url

Tags: regex

I am using the code below to try to match http(s) with anything after it up to zero or one spaces. This somewhat works but captures everything in the string.

```
/(http.*)\s*/i
```

for example if I use `http://google.com/whatever (it captures this too)` whereas I just want `http://google.com/whatever`

Comment: here is a pattern `http[^ ]+ ?` and you can see [it here](https://regex101.com/r/7zc8mv/1)., please notice it is not a complete pattern, since I did not use (s) for http, so may need to tweak it feather

Comment: An alternative https://regexr.com/5rm9f

Comment: Or like `https?:\/\/\S+\s*` https://regex101.com/r/8V7xxb/1

Comment: @thefourthbird If you will put that as an answer I will accept it as correct

Comment: @james I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match the protocol with optional s and 1 or more non whitespace chars using `\S+`. At the end of the match, you can match optional whitespace chars using `\s*`

```
https?://\S+\s*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/95TxtI/1)